# Change vertical alignment of tabulary

Tags: tables, tabulary

Is there some easy way to change the baseline used by `tabulary`'s `LCRJ` columns as I show with `tabular`'s `b` column and `tabularx`'s `X` column?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \caption{A regular \texttt{tabular}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\hangindent=1em}b{4.5cm} c c}
      A & B & C \\
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit & 123 & 456 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}
    \caption{A \texttt{tabularx}}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
    \begin{tabularx}{6.75cm}{>{\raggedright\hangindent=1em}X c c}
      A & B & C \\
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit & 123 & 456 \\
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}
    \caption{A \texttt{tabulary}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabulary}{6.75cm}{>{\raggedright\hangindent=1em}L c c}
      A & B & C \\
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit & 123 & 456 \\
    \end{tabulary}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TY uses

```
\def\TY@box@v#1{%
      \vtop \@startpbox{\csname TY@F\the\TY@count\endcsname}%
              #1\arraybackslash\tyformat
                              \insert@column\@endpbox}
```

so if you remade this definition after loading the package but with `\vbox` instead of `\vtop` it would act like `b` columns rather than `p` columns.

This might not be the most intuitive interface ever designed but....

Comment: Great! For posterity, how would one make it act like `m` columns? (Not that I can ever see myself using that.)

Comment: @FredrikP replace `\vtop` by `$\vcenter`  and stick a matching `$` after endpbox